# BigQuery ST_MakeLine vs PostGIS ST_MakeLine

Tags: postgis, postgresql, google-big-query

### Description

I'm trying to move our database from `BigQuery` to `PostgreSQL`. The issue that I'm encountering is that calculated distance for a line, built from same GPS traces,  are way different in `PostGIS` when compared to `BigQuery`.

I have a database that stores GPS coordinates collected over time from a tracking device. I need to calculate GPS distance traveled throughout the given period of time.

For that, in `BigQuery`, I aggregate all points to array, then make a line from them, using `ST_MakeLine` and finally, calculate the length of the line using `ST_Length`.

That works pretty well, and the distance, most of the time, is pretty accurate.

Now on `PostgreSQL`, using `PostGIS`, the results of such query, over the same dataset is very different.

When, for the same dataset, `BigQuery` calculates 722.48km, which is pretty close to the actual distance traveled, `PostGIS` calculates 852.26km.

The shapes themselves looks quite similar (please see the screenshot, where blue is shape from `BigQuery` and black is shape from `PostgreSQL`)

[image: Shapes]

### Question

How could I achieve similar results in BigQuery?

### Notes

I've noticed that `BigQuery`, when using `ST_MakeLine` creates `MULTILINESTRING`, while `PostGIS` creates `LINESTRING`. I've also read on the internet that `BigQuery`'s `ST_MakeLine` removes overlapping lines from the geometry. That would make sense, because as it is known, GPS might be inaccurate at times and send multiple incorrect coordinates. Could that be true and the reason behind this issue? If no, what else could be causing it?

### Queries

PostgreSQL Query:

```
WITH data as (
    SELECT 
        date(timestamp) as date,
        ST_Point(longitude, latitude, 4326) as point,
        timestamp
    FROM locations 
    WHERE timestamp >= '2022-09-30 00:00:00+00' AND timestamp < '2022-10-01 00:00:00+00'
), grouped_data as (
    SELECT 
        date,
        ST_Length(
            ST_MakeLine(point ORDER BY timestamp ASC),
            false
        ) as distance
    FROM data
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date DESC
)

select * from grouped_data;
```

And BigQuery query:

```
WITH data as (
  SELECT 
    DATE(timestamp) date,
    ST_GEOGPOINT(longitude, latitude) point,
    timestamp
  FROM `locations` 
  WHERE DATE(timestamp) >= "2022-09-30" AND DATE(timestamp) < "2022-10-01"
  ORDER BY timestamp asc
), grouped_data as (
  SELECT
    date,
    ST_LENGTH(
      ST_MAKELINE(
        array_agg(
          point order by timestamp asc
        )
      )
    ) distance
  FROM data
  GROUP BY date
  ORDER BY date DESC
)

select * from grouped_data;
```

### Data

I've uploaded the wkt files generated from both engines and the dataset in question in csv format to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LVg-j3Q5IK1zEDeR8eGF_DFwGOjX3Meq?usp=sharing)

Comment: I can't quite read your code but do you use "geography" data type in PostGIS? Could you add the route geometry as WKT?

Comment: One test you can do in PostGIS is pass the LineString created by PostGIS through ST_UnaryUnion. It should do duplicate-sections removal as BigQuery, e.g. `st_unaryunion(st_geomfromtext('linestring(1 0, 2 0, 1.5 0, 1.5 3)'))` results in `MULTILINESTRING((1 0,1.5 0),(1.5 0,2 0),(1.5 0,1.5 3))`.

Comment: @Michael That indeed seems to do something in a good direction. However the result still isn't equal, as it then returns 749.64km. I'll update the question with dataset and WKT files for more information.

Comment: Yes, i would not expect exact same result, snapping algorithms and tolerance are somewhat different between platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues.  The first is that you are not using the spheroid for your length calculation - the `false` in your st_length.  The second is that you are creating the points as `geometry` type, then it appears you are trying to use them as `geography` type - the `use_spheroid` option, which you have as `false` only works for geography types.  To remove the overlaps, you can use `st_linemerge`.  This may work for you:

```
WITH data as (
    SELECT 
        date(timestamp) as date,
        ST_Point(longitude, latitude, 4326) as point,
        timestamp
    FROM locations 
    WHERE timestamp >= '2022-09-30 00:00:00+00' AND timestamp < '2022-10-01 00:00:00+00'
), grouped_data as (
    SELECT 
        date,
        ST_Length(
            st_linemerge(ST_MakeLine(point ORDER BY timestamp ASC))::geography) as distance
    FROM data
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date DESC
)

select * from grouped_data;
```

Upon testing `st_length` with geometry, and setting the `use_spheroid` option to either true or false, it appears postgis is automatically casting it to geography.  However, this isn't in the docs anywhere so it's probably safer to make sure to cast your geometry to geography explicitly (as in my code sample).